# Return string from second function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Well i have created a function to return the picture url. 
See code below:

```
function loadAttachment(itemid) {
    web = context.get_web();
    attachmentFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Lists/LijstMedewerkers/Attachments/" + itemid);
    attachmentFiles = attachmentFolder.get_files();
    //Load attachments
    context.load(attachmentFiles);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onLoaddAttachmentSuccess, onLoadAttachmentFail);
    alert(picture);
    return picture;
}

function onLoadAttachmentFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get lists items. Error:' + args.get_message());
}

function onLoaddAttachmentSuccess(sender, args) {
    // Enumerate and list the Asset Attachments if they exist
    var attachementEnumerator = attachmentFiles.getEnumerator();
    while (attachementEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var attachment = attachementEnumerator.get_current();
        picture = attachment.get_serverRelativeUrl();
    }
}
```

Well it's not returning the value of the picture. When i do an alert i see the value but with the return it's not working. even if i put the picture in the itemid.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: `executeQueryAsync` is asynchronous. You should probably  move the code that you want to execute upon imageloading into your callback `onLoaddAttachmentSuccess`. Also I don't see where `picture` is declared in `loadAttachment`

Comment: the picture is declared above the function. But i tried to return it in onLoaddAttachmentSuccess but it's not working also.

Comment: no solution for an asynchronous function ?

Answer (score 0):

Since [SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is *async*:

```
SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeededCallback, failedCallback)
```

`succeededCallback` is used for declaring function that contains the returned results.

When working with asynchronous API such as JSOM the following patterns are commonly used:

- Using nested callbacks
- Using the promises pattern

The below example demonstrates how to retrieve attachment files using callback approach:

```
function loadAttachments(listTitle, itemId,success,error) {
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var listItem = list.getItemById(itemId);
   var files = listItem.get_attachmentFiles();
   context.load(files);
   context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
     success(files);
    }, 
    error);
}
```

Usage

Get first file attachment url

```
loadAttachments('Projects',3,
function(attachmentFiles){
    if(attachmentFiles.get_count() > 0) {
       var attachmentFile = attachmentFiles.getItemAtIndex(0);
       var fileUrl = attachmentFile.get_serverRelativeUrl();
       //...
    }
},
function(sender,args){
   console.log(args.get_message()); 
});
```